# How to post data to firestore avoiding non-existent documents?

Tags: r, google-cloud-firestore, httr

I have a data structure similar to this that I want to post to firestore database via REST API:

[image]

I manually created the `House1` document, then `Floor1` and `Ground`.

[image]

`Ground` contains the data:

[image]

### REST API in R

Now, I am trying to use the firestore REST API in R to create the same thing.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

# POST function
post_data_to_firestore <- function(path, data, auth_token) {
  r <- httr::POST(
    url = sprintf("https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/%s", path),
    config = httr::add_headers(
      "Content-Type" = "application/json",
      "Authorization" = paste("Bearer", auth_token)
    ),
    body = data
  )
  return(r)
}

PROJECT_NAME <- "firebase-project"
COLLECTION <- "Block"
accessTokenu <- "access-token"

endpoint <- paste0("projects/", PROJECT_NAME, "/databases/(default)/documents/", COLLECTION)

data_list <- toJSON(
    list(
    fields = list(
      Name = list("stringValue" = "Ground")
    )
  ), auto_unbox = TRUE
)

post_data_to_firestore(
  path = paste0(endpoint, "/House2/Floor1", "?documentId=", "Ground"),
  data = data_list,
  auth_token = accessTokenu
)
```

This creates `House2` which is a non-existent document according to firestore. I understand that all I have created here is only `Ground` that contains `Name`:

[image]

#### Question

How do I change my POST request to ensure that I properly create documents so that I can query them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you manually added `House1` using the Firebase Console, you would have clicked the "Add Document" button for `House1`, then you clicked "Start Collection" for `Floor1`, then you clicked "Add Document" for `Ground` and again for `Top`.

So manually (via Firebase Console) you created 3 documents:

- `Block/House1`
- `Block/House1/Floor1/Ground`
- `Block/House1/Floor1/Top`

But your REST API is creating a single document:

- `Block/House2/Floor1/Ground`

Comment: So if I want to create Block/House1 what should I include in `data` argument in my function?

Comment: Whatever is appropriate for your application.  Note: you are not REQUIRED to have a `House2` document.....unless you are trying to use `listDocuments` functionality which I would suggest is not a good way to design an app.  Rather: put *data* into documents and Query the collection the documents are in.  For most use cases, it is not a good (nor scalable) idea to have functionality that depends on "get me all the docs in this collection".

Comment: And if it isn't apparent....if you delete `House1` via an API, the documents `House1/Floor1/Ground` and `House1/Floor1/Top` will NOT be deleted.  If  you delete it via Firebase Console, it WILL delete those "nested documents" but that is Firebase Console doing some "UI magic"....it is not how Firestore's API itself works.

Comment: This is what I'd need to create the document `House2`. I don't need the data argument.:
`post_data_to_firestore(
  path = paste0(endpoint, "?documentId=", "House2"),
  data = NULL,
  auth_token = accessTokenu
)`

Comment: I don't know if you can post NULL data to a document.  I would expect it would require at least *something* in it.  But if the document is to be empty...why create it?

Comment: A good reason for me is that I can visually see how everything is related. I know it is not a good practice but I still need better understanding of documents to come up with a reasonable design that I can easily query. This structure is something I can easily query and also create.

Comment: Actually, I do run another post request that then adds the subcollection and the `Ground` document. I don't know if `House2` is technically containing it or not, but I can create and query it easily.

Comment: Firebase Console is not an "admin UI" for your app.  You almost certainly will end up building your own "admin screens" into your app, or even an entire "admin app".  Do not get too hooked on Firebase Console.  It is there to admin your PROJECT, not the data in your app.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to perform a separate POST call for each document in this nested structure. There is no single API call that creates a deeply nested child and all parent documents.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to change `post_data_to_firestore`.  You just need to call it once for each individual document you want to create.  Firestore will not automatically create documents in the middle of a path.  It will just create the one document for the one path you provide in the request.  It works the same way for the client libraries that wrap the underlying protocol.